# Qt Gestures. Not receiving qgesture events

Tags: c++, windows, qt

I am trying to get QGesture events in my widget (subclass of QWidget). I have the following in my constructor:

```
setAttribute(Qt::WA_AcceptTouchEvents);
setAttribute(Qt::WA_TouchPadAcceptSingleTouchEvents);
grabGesture(Qt::SwipeGesture);
grabGesture(Qt::PanGesture);
grabGesture(Qt::PinchGesture);
```

And I have my own event function:

```
bool MyWidget::event(QEvent *event)
{
  if(event->type() == QEvent::Gesture)
  {
    TRACE("Gesture");
  }
  if(event->type() == QEvent::GestureOverride)
  {
    TRACE("Gesture override");
  }
  if(event->type() == QEvent::Enter)
  {
    TRACE("Mouse enter");
  }
  return true;
}
```

On windows 7 I receive mouse enter events but nothing else. (I am using the ms surface sdk input simulator to generate touch events as suggested [here](https://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/11918)). Very occasionally I get the message

```
QGestureManager::deliverEvent: could not find the target for gesture.
```

but cannot easily reproduce this.

Why am I not receiving gesture events?

Comment: Is it possible that the MS Surface SDK input simulator doesn't generate touch events that are compatible with the Qt event system? From what you've described it really seems like the case. I have a Raspberry Pi with the 7" official multi-touch screen and Qt's touch functionality works without any issues whatsoever.

Answer (score 2):

You must not set the `Qt::WA_TouchPadAcceptSingleTouchEvents` on a widget. The documentation for [`enum Qt::WidgetAttribute`](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt-5.2/qt.html#WidgetAttribute-enum) lists the respective attribute in a section preceded by

> **Warning:** This flag must never be set or cleared by the widget's author.

This used to be more explicit in earlier documentation (e.g. [`enum Qt::WidgetAttribute` for Qt 4.8](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qt.html#WidgetAttribute-enum)).

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a parent mainwindow to be able to grab the gestures, see [QTBUG #14224](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-14224).

Comment: I tried making sure my widget has a QMainWindow parent but this doesn't help. I also tried the imagegestures qt example and no gestures are recognised using the ms surface sdk input simulator. I also tried the imagegestures example on ios 5 on an ipad 1 and no gestures are recognised there either.