# Receive gestures in PyQt5 (for Android)

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, swipe, gesture

Ok, this question has been asked before - but I didn't find an answer yet..

I'm trying to left/right swipe between images using a `QLabel` but I didn't manage to receive *any* gesture events yet with my PyQt5 based application.
Here is what I have:

```
class MyViewer(QtWidgets.QLabel):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent=parent)
        self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_AcceptTouchEvents)  # just gave it a try
        self.grabGesture(QtCore.Qt.SwipeGesture)

    def event(self, event):
        if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.Gesture:  # <= this won't happen
            print("Hello event!")
        return super().event(event)
```

I also tried to look for `QtWidgets.QGestureEvent` but even when I just print out `event.type()` I only see events seemingly unrelated to any gestures (except some `QToucheEvent` instances)

Similar questions are [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21548898/qt-gestures-not-receiving-qgesture-events), [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63809142/swipe-gesture-to-change-frames-images-in-pyqt5), [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14318861/qt-gestures-tapandhold-and-swipe-are-not-recognized) and I even read [some documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/gestures-overview.html) but I didn't see a working example yet. Only questions and example C++ snippets..

I'm using PyQt5.15.0 for both Linux and Android and I didn't see a single trace of anything gesture-ish yet.
What did I forget to do? Does the parent have to be set up somehow?

Answer (score 0):

How many fingers were you swiping with? According to [the Qt forum](https://forum.qt.io/topic/61404/qt-swipe-gesture-not-working/7), `Qt.SwipeGesture` is only registered when swiping with two or more fingers, depending on the platform. One finger is represented as a `QtGui.QMouseEvent`.

If you have been using two or more fingers, it is also possible that the reason that you saw no events is because you did not explictly accept them. The [docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/gestures-overview.html) say:

> A QGesture is by default accepted when it arrives at your widget. **However, it is good practice to always explicitly accept or reject a gesture.** The general rule is that, if you accept a gesture, you are using it. If you are ignoring it you are not interested in it. **Ignoring a gesture may mean it gets offered to another target object, or it will get canceled.** [...] **Ignoring the gesture will mean the gesture will never be offered to you again.**